# Inclusion-Exclusion principle for $A\wedge B$

Tags: probability

> Let $A,B$ events and $A\wedge B:=((A\cup B) \setminus (A \cap B))$. Prove that:
>
> a. $P(A\wedge B)=P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B)$
>
> b. $(A \wedge B)\wedge C=A \wedge (B \wedge C)$
>
> c. $ P(A \wedge B \wedge C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-2P(A\cap B)-2P(A\cap C)-2P(B\cap C)+3P(A \cup B\cup C)$
>
> d. Give a formula similar to inclusion-exclusion principle for $P(\displaystyle\bigwedge_{i=1}^n A_i)$

A. can be solved by simply using the definition and the fact that $P(A\setminus B)=P(A)-P(B)$: $$P(A\wedge B)=P(A\cup B)-P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B).$$

About B:First I simplified it until had to prove equation I know how to solve from discrete math (containing the sides in each other).

About C: somewhere I think I have mistake. I did the following steps:
$$ \begin{align*}
&P(A\wedge B \wedge C)\\
&=P(A \wedge B)+P(C)-2P((A\wedge B) \cap C) \\
&=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-2P(A\cap C)+2P((A\wedge B) \cap C)\\
&=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-2P(A\cap C)+2[P((A\cup B)\cap C)-P(A\cap B)]\\
&=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-2P(A\cap C)-2P(A\cap B)+2(P(A\cup B)+P(C)+P(A\cup B\cup C))\\
&=P(A)+P(B)+3P(C)+2P(A\cup B)-2P(A\cap B)-2P(A\cap C)+2P(A\cup B\cup C)\\
\end{align*}. $$

This is absolutely not the right result.
About D: I don't have any clever ideas.

What is the mistake in C and what is the basic strategy for solving question like D (Writing formulas for probability principles e.g inclusion and exclusion)?

Comment: I think a lot of math books would write this as $A\Delta B$ rather than $A\wedge B$

Comment: Between the second line and the third line, you've changed the sign of $P((A\wedge B)\cap C)$.

Comment: I think you might want to use that $(A\wedge B)\cap C=(A\cap C)\wedge (B\cap C)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I'll check it. thanks. What about D? Is it something similar to $\displaystyle P(\bigwedge A_i)=\sum_{k=1}^n P(A_i)-2\sum {A_i\cap A_j}+3\sum{A_i\cap A_j \cap A_l}...+(-1)^{n-1}nP(\bigcup_{i=1} A_i)$ [where $1\le j,k,l\le i \le n$] and prove it by induction?

Comment: Hmm...did you make a typo anywhere? I claim that $P(A \land B \land C)$ is given by the formula:
$$
P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-2P(A\cap B)-2P(A\cap C)-2P(B\cap C)+4P(A \cap B\cap C)
$$

Comment: Yeah, the formula in the question for $P(A\wedge B\wedge C)$ is wrong. Note that if $A,B,C$ are pairwise disjoint, then $P(A\wedge B\wedge C)=P(A\cup B\cup C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)$. But your formula gives $P(A\wedge B\wedge C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)+3P(A\cup B\cup C)$, which is transparently wrong. @Adriano is correct, the last term should be $4P(A\cap B\cap C)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I'm not sure that $(A\wedge B)\cap C=(A\cap C)\wedge (B\cap C)$. Evaluating the sides gives $((A\cap C)\cup (B \cup C))\setminus (A\cup B)\neq ((A\cap C)\cup (B \cup C))\setminus (A\cap B \cap C)$. If I missed something and the equlation is correct, indeed there is a mistake in the question and I'd change my answer in D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About (d), for every $I\subset\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, call $A_I=\bigcap\limits_{i\in I}A_i$, then
$$
P(A_1\triangle A_2\triangle\cdots\triangle A_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i+1}2^{i-1}\sum_{|I|=i}P(A_I).
$$
**Nota:**

- For example, $ P(A \triangle B \triangle C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-2P(A\cap B)-2P(A\cap C)$ $-2P(B\cap C)+4P(A \cap B\cap C)$.
- Indeed, $(A\triangle B)\cap C=(A\cap C)\triangle(B\cap C)$.

Comment: Why is the second dot correct?

Comment: A Venn diagram gives it in two seconds.

Comment: I know but I look for a proof that doesn't use Venn diagram.

Comment: Then indicator functions (but now count twenty seconds). To begin with $\mathbf 1_{A\triangle B}=\mathbf 1_A+\mathbf 1_B-2\mathbf 1_A\mathbf 1_B$ and $\mathbf 1_{D\cap C}=\mathbf 1_D\mathbf 1_C$ hence...

Comment: o.k. how can I prove the formula you gave?

Comment: Did you try a recursion on $n$?

Comment: solved: I used induction and it works. By the way: the formula is with $2^{i-1}$ (not $2^i$) and it can shown from the first dot. thanks.